# How to show only one notification in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications, push-notification

I have created Chrome extension and use pusher to receive some data from server.
When I test it show multiple duplicate data because it follow tabs that I opened.
anyone understand me.Help me please.Thank you in advance.

```
Content.js

Pusher.Util.getLocalStorage = function() 
{ 
 return undefined; 
}
Pusher.ScriptRequest.prototype.send = function(receiver) {
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("GET", this.src, true);
 xhr.send();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
          if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
            Notification.requestPermission();
        });
        var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        var notificationsChannel = pusher.subscribe('notifications');
        notificationsChannel.bind('new_notification', function(notification){
            // assign the notification's message to a <div></div>
            var message = notification.message;
            if (!Notification) {
                alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
                return;
              }
            if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
                Notification.requestPermission();
            else {
                console.log(message);
                var notification = new Notification('แจ้งเตือน', {
                  icon: 'img/LOGO.png',
                  body: message,
                });
                notification.onclick = function () {
                  location.reload();      
                };

              }
        });
```

[duplicate notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFv1i.png)